# setValue for Key to a class object in swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, mirroring, key-value-coding

In objective-c we can use `setValue:forKey` method on any object, including class object. Is there a way to achieve the same in swift?

What I want to do here is I have `NSManagedObject` subclass and I have another model object for the same entity but non managed object. This way, within coredata stack, I can use the managed object and outside of it I can use normal modal.

Now my need is that when I have model object available and have the entity name, I want to populate all values from one object to another. For that, I am using object mirroring to get variable name and value from first object.

The challenge is how to set the value for the variable name (which I have in string) for the second object. Objective-C's `setValue:forKey` was very useful here.

Comment: As long as your class conforms to [`NSKeyValueCoding`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/nskeyvaluecoding) or inherits from `NSObject` then you can use the key-value functions

Comment: Either inherit from `NSObject` or implement `setValue(_ value: Any?, key: String)` in the Swift struct/class then call it for each entry in your dictionary.